# pyspark from_json changing the decimal for a json read as string

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

UDF returning json as string, but when reading it in main function, decimal format is getting change. If i change the attribute from decimal to string, i can get the full number.

```java
{
  "Organization":"Org",
   "Employee": 
       {
         "Id":  2345678945.1234512    // this is decimal in json but while reading from UDF, decimal part is not coming correctly
         "name" : "somename"
        }
}

//UDF with signature
string myFunc(string)
{
   return json.serialize(myObject);
}

//myObject is complex object and  looks like
Class myObject
{
   string Organization;
   Employee Emp;
}

class Employee
{
  decimal Id;   //if i change it to string, i get full value
  string name;
}
```

In my main function i am calling the UDF as

```java
df = df.Select(myFunc(col('col1')).As(jsonResult));

// json schema
schema = {StructField(Organization, StringType),
                  StructFiled(Employee, StringType)}    // reading json as String type

//explode json
df = df.Select(FromJson(Col("jsonResult"), schema).As("Result")) 

df.Select("Result.*").

df.Select("Employee")  // reading json attribute as string, but decimal is getting truncated.
```

Comment: Why are you not using `StructType` for `Employee` field?

Comment: have you tried to use [`from_json`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.from_json) and [`to_json`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.to_json) instead of (de)serialize manually using UDF?